# EF Core multiple "where" are not translated

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a db model that I want to filter (during runtime) on different attributes. For that I have methods each running a "where" clause depending on the attribute and return an IQueryable. Thing is that the clause cannot be translated to SQL, so the query runs with no "WHERE" statements, returns the whole table and the server is doing the filtering, which is both slow and expensive.

From the logs, I get a message:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression
>   'where (new EntityId([ed].EntityId).Id == __entityId_Id_1)' could not
>   be translated and will be evaluated locally.

My question is: am I on the right track here, or not? And if yes where should I look next?

Main function(s)

```cs
public static EntityDataDTO GetEntityByKey(this IQueryable<EntityDTO> query, IEntityId entityId, EntityTypeDTO type, string key)
{
    return query
        .HasEntity(entityId)
        .HasType(type)
        .HasKey(key)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}

public static EntityDataDTO GetEntity(this IQueryable<EntityDTO> query, IEntityId entityId, EntityTypeDTO type)
{
    return query
        .HasEntity(entityId)
        .HasType(type)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Subfunctions

```cs
public static IQueryable<EntityDDTO> HasType(this IQueryable<EntityDTO> query, EntityTypeDTO type)
{
    return query.Where(ed => ed.Type == type);
}

public static IQueryable<EntityDTO> HasEntity(this IQueryable<EntityDTO> query, IEntityId entityId)
{
    return query.Where(ed => ed.EntityId.Id == entityId.Id);
}
```

EntityDTO

```cs
public class EntityDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public EntityTypeDTO Type { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public IEntityId EntityId { get; set; }
        public IPartnerId PartnerId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: consider converting the criteria into Expression and use the Where clause. check out [this link](https://coderethinked.com/don-t-use-func-delegate-on-the-ef-entities/)

Comment: Show your `EntityDTO` class

Comment: Why are you using Dtos as entities?! DTO = Domain Transfer Object, where an entity (in conjunction with EF Core/ORMs) represents the database structure. Not clear what you try to achieve

Comment: Most likely the problem is the interface `IEntityId` - EF (Core) does not play well with interfaces (except collection related), nor "value objects".

Answer (score 2):

I see no issue with any of the code you've posted. However, you neglected to post the definition of your `HasKey` method, so I'm assuming the issue is actually there.

In any case, the warning is telling you exactly what the problematic code is: `new EntityId(ed.EntityId).Id`. Find that bit of code and correct it. Something like a call to new up a type cannot be translated to SQL, so EF must run that in memory. Technically, you can proceed and just allow EF to do this. However, that's generally a sign that you're going to running inefficient queries, so you should look for a better way that doesn't involve having to run that part of the query in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Chris! That's exactly my problem. It works as is, but it s very inefficient and as the app grows this will be a big stepback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression predicates and build yourself a library of common reusable expressions. Here's an example of adding this to your EntityDTO, note that it returns an expression and not the actual IQueryable/IEnumerable:

```
public partial class EntityDTO
{
  public static Expression<Func<EntityDTO, bool>> HasType(EntityTypeDTO type)
  {
    return ed => ed.Type == type;
  }
  public static Expression<Func<EntityDTO, bool>> HasEntity(IEntityId entityId)
  {
      return ed => ed.EntityId.Id == entityId.Id;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not the issue. The OP is using extensions on `IQueryable`, which is an alternative method to this expression-based approach, but equally viable.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Agreed. both viable considering the OP uses a DTO. But wouldn't the expression approach be best practice? Especially if implemented in the data access code?

Comment: Not necessarily, and especially since these classes seem to be misnamed. If they're being queried, then they're entities, not DTOs, and definitely not domain objects. So, this just boils down to simple query extensions.